# Exchange Rate Key Value Lookup With Weird JSON File Format

Tags: swiftui, ios14

I need help with currency exchange rate lookup given a key (3 digit currency code). The JSON object is rather unusual with no lablels such as date, timestamp, success, or rate. The first string value is the base or home currency. In the example below it is "usd" (US dollars).

I would like to cycle through all the currencies to get each exchange rate by giving its 3 digit currency code and storing it in an ordered array.

```
{
    "usd": {
        "aed": 4.420217,
        "afn": 93.3213,
        "all": 123.104693,
        "amd": 628.026474,
        "ang": 2.159569,
        "aoa": 791.552347,
        "ars": 111.887966,
        "aud": 1.558363,
        "awg": 2.164862,
        "azn": 2.045728,
        "bam": 1.9541,
        "bbd": 2.429065,
        "bch": 0.001278
    }
}
```

In a slightly different formatted JSON object I used the following loop to copy exchange rates to an ordered array.

```
 for index in 0..<userData.rateArray.count {
      currencyCode = currCode[index]
                   
           if let unwrapped = results.rates[currencyCode] {
                  userData.rateArray[index]   = 1.0 / unwrapped
           }
      }
```

The follow code is the API used to get the 3 digit currency codes and the exchange rates (called via UpdateRates).

```
class GetCurrency: Codable {
    
    let id = UUID()
    var getCurrencies: [String : [String: Double]] = [:]
    
    required public init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        do{
            print(#function)
            let baseContainer = try decoder.singleValueContainer()
            let base = try baseContainer.decode([String : [String: Double]].self)
            for key in base.keys{
                getCurrencies[key] = base[key]
            }
        }catch{
            print(error)
            throw error
        }
    }
}


class CurrencyViewModel: ObservableObject{
    
    @Published var results: GetCurrency?
    @Published var selectedBaseCurrency: String = "usd"
        
    func UpdateRates() {
        
        let baseUrl = "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/fawazahmed0/currency-api@1/latest/currencies/"
        let baseCur = selectedBaseCurrency   // usd, eur, cad, etc
        let requestType = ".json"
        
        guard let url = URL(string: baseUrl + baseCur + requestType) else {
            print("Invalid URL")
            return
        }
        let request = URLRequest(url: url)

        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
            if let data = data {
                do{
                    let decodedResponse = try JSONDecoder().decode(GetCurrency.self, from: data)
                    
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.results = decodedResponse
                         
                        // this prints out the complete table of currency code and exchange rates
                        print(self.results?.getCurrencies["usd"] ?? 0.0)
                       
                    }
                } catch {
                    //Error thrown by a try
                    print(error)//much more informative than error?.localizedDescription
                }
            }
            if error != nil {
                //data task error
                print(error!)
            }
        }.resume()
    }
}
```

Comment: if you already have "usd" `self.results?.getCurrencies["usd"]?.keys` gives you the 3 letter code/key for the rest of currencies when you put it in a loop. If you change your `UpdateRates()` to `func UpdateRates(baseCurrency: String)` to take in a parameter and change it to use the parameter `let baseCur = baseCurrency` you can call `UpdateRates(baseCurrency: key)` in your loop.

Comment: I am having trouble with the onAppear call to UpdateRates:  .onAppear(perform: vm.UpdateRates(baseCur: baseCurrency.baseCur.baseS)).  It is giving the error Cannot convert value of type '()' to expected argument type '(() -> Void)?'  To prevent confusion with my base currency structure I changed the parameter passed to UpdateRates to baseCur.  The system base currency in stored in the structure baseCurrency.baseCur and baseS is the base currency 3 digit string.

Comment: You are missing some brackets make the onAppear method like the one I used in your previous question.

Comment: Ok I got the onAppear working; I see it doesn't need the perform keyword.     in UpdateRates I can print(self.results?getCurrencies[baseCur]?.values ?? 0.0)  and it gives me a large table of exchange rates for baseCur base currency.  So how do I iterate over these values with the 3 digit currency code to get a single value for a given key?

Comment: You iterate over the keys look at the first comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks lorem ipsum for your help. Below is the updated ASI logic that copies the exchange rates to the rateArray using key/value lookups.

```
class CurrencyViewModel: ObservableObject{
    
    @Published var results: GetCurrency?
    @Published var rateArray = [Double] ()
    
    init() {
        if UserDefaults.standard.array(forKey: "rates") != nil {
            rateArray = UserDefaults.standard.array(forKey: "rates") as! [Double]
        }else {
            rateArray = [Double] (repeating: 0.0, count: 160)
            UserDefaults.standard.set(self.rateArray, forKey: "rates")
        }
    }
    
    func updateRates(baseCur: String) {
        
            ...

                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.results = decodedResponse
                        
                        // loop through all available currencies
                        for index in 0..<currCode.count {
                            currencyCode = currCode[index]
                            
                            // spacial handling for base currency
                            if currencyCode == baseCur {
                                self.rateArray[index] = 1.0000
                            } else {
                                
                                let homeRate = self.results?.getCurrencies[baseCur]
                        
                                // complement and save the exchange rate
                                if let unwrapped = homeRate?[currencyCode] {
                                    self.rateArray[index] = 1.0 / unwrapped
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                } catch {
                    //Error thrown by a try
                    print(error)//much more informative than error?.localizedDescription
                }
            }
            if error != nil {
                //data task error
                print(error!)
            }
        }.resume()
    }
}
```